# Is part of the gmail API for Java missing?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

If you got to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_2_install_the_gmail_client_library , it says you must download two zip files. However, I can only find one.

I can't seem to find the zip file referring to step 4, 'google-api-services-gmail-v1-[version].jar'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still getting setup, they are already in the Maven replacement repository though:

https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~google-api-services-gmail

(The latest one, which was just posted earlier today.)

Comment: I would vote you up, but I need 15 reputation first :(